# Insert Context from another document in Mail Merge

Tags: .net, mailmerge, word-2007, word-template

I have a word template which I am using to generate a word document. I am adding some fields dynamically using mail-merge.

There is one whole page in the template which I want to be displayed only if a database field "Marks" value is null. That is if "Marks" is null then word document generated has Page 1, 2 and 3 but if the value is not null then only Page 1 and Page 3 should be displayed.

I know one option is to created two templates, first with two pages and second with three pages. But that will keep doubling my templates each time I need to add something with conditions.

How can I achieve this functionality in single template ?